# Handle text in the flexbox layout - How to avoid text to go cross on other elements?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox layout with 3 "containers".
Two "lines" and one big "container" taking all the remaining space.

The text in my first "line" does not "shrink" to stay inside the first "container" but goes below the second "line".

I've seen there was a nowrap property but it does not seem to resolve the situation.

An idea ?

I've tried to make a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Odovad/4nhadjdf/) to show you what the problem is.
I don't know why my map is not showing.
I would like the text to stay on the good line with no effect on the map.
(that have to take all the available place)

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <div id="header" class="text-center">
    <a href="/"></a>This is something I want to be displayed only on this line with no effect below</div>
  <div id="lineboard">
    <div class="col-md-3">Word 1:</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Word 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Word 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Word 4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: osmAttrib
  });

// initialize the map on the "map" div with a given center and zoom
var map = L.map('map').setView([19.04469, 72.9258], 12).addLayer(osm);
```

CSS

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  font: 30px Georgia, serif;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
}

#lineboard {
  font: 20px Georgia, serif;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #1E3258;
  color: white;
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#map {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide some working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the text wrapped and staying on the first container but not going below the `#lineboard` you should change `height: 80px` to `min-height: 80px` on the `#header`.

Comment: It does not work like I want; the space taken by the map is modified.

Comment: The flex property seems to be overridden.

Comment: Ok, I changed the answer. I hope that's what you are trying to do. =D